# React js truncate text with ellipsis in the middle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I could not find a simple solution for this issue. I would like to truncate text with ellipsis in the middle. I have found the module [react-middle-ellipsis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-middle-ellipsis) which kinda works, but has the issues of shorthening the string too much and an issue that text can still overflow the element it is in (not more than one character), before being truncated. I would like to use a close alternative of `textOverflow: "some-dynamic-string"`, but that is supported only in Firefox. So far:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import MiddleEllipsis from "react-middle-ellipsis";
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  tileHeader: {
      width: '80%',
      height: '30%'
})

const Component = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return(
     <div className={classes.tileHeader}>
         <MiddleEllipsis><Typography variant="h4">some-very-long-text</Typography></MiddleEllipsis>
     </div>)
}
```

As I said, this kinda works but the edge cases, which are crutial for me and I cannot resolve the issue. I tried to set a padding for the `tileHeader`, but that does not do anything. The working approximation for Firefox

```
  return(
      <div className={classes.tileHeader}>
            <Typography variant="h4" noWrap style={{ textOverflow: `"some-dynamic-string"`}}>some-very-long-text</Typography>
      </div>)
```

For the `looooooooooooooooong` string I want it rather be `loo...ong` not `looooo...` string which the mentioned module does. The edge case 1 - shorting the string too much can be overcome by copying the code from the github of the mentioned module and adjusting it myself. The edge case 2 - not truncating soon enought - which means when resizing the window, the text can get to a position where it overflows the element, before it being truncated. See image - right before truncating by the module:

[image: before truncation]

A bit more tighter and it finally triggers:
[image: after truncation]

Comment: What do you mean "ellipsis in the middle" - do you want your text to all be on one line with some letters from the beginning and end of the string, with an ellipsis in the middle rather than at the end? It's also unclear what issue you're facing is: "the edge cases" "I cannot resolve" - please be specific when asking questions about what you're expecting to work and what isn't working.

Comment: @AndyRay Understood, added examples with explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I have published an npm package related to this issue that is [use-truncate-from-middle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-truncate-from-middle) hook.
I tried the situation above with latest version material-ui and it seems to work:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTruncateFromMiddle } from 'use-truncate-from-middle';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

const TruncateExample = () => {
  const textRef = React.useRef(null);
  const { truncatedText } = useTruncateFromMiddle({
    ref: textRef,
    originalText: 'loooooooooooooong',
    middleChars: '...',
  });

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        maxWidth: 250,
        marginTop: 32,
      }}
    >
      <div style={{ width: '80%', height: '30%' }}>
        <Typography ref={textRef} variant="h4">
          {truncatedText}
        </Typography>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TruncateExample;
```

[image: Edit vigilant-elion-6zg6im]

Comment: The package does not work properly. When you resize it is going crazy :(

Comment: sorry for the late reply. you are right @KrystianSztadhaus.  I created an [issue](https://github.com/definite2/use-dynamic-truncate-middle/issues/1) to the package. I will inform you back when resolve the issue. Thank you for informing me.

Answer (score 1):

[react-truncate-inside](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-truncate-inside?activeTab=readme) allow you to add an ellipsis in the middle of a single-line text.

It supports alternative ellipsis and work fine on resize.

[image]